How can i print images using thermal using android app but getting some random text
Trying to print image from thermal printer using our own android app but its not printing instead its printing some random characters  so on.
it's working well for text but not for images.
Here im adding my code Please have a look on my code.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private static final UUID BT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        Button printButton = findViewById(R.id.printButton);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        connectButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String printerAddress = "Your_Adderss"; // Replace with your printer's Bluetooth address
            connectToBluetoothPrinter(printerAddress);
        });

        printButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            printImage();
        });
    }

    private void connectToBluetoothPrinter(String address) {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            showToast("Bluetooth not supported on this device");
            return;
        }

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            showToast("Please enable Bluetooth and try again");
            return;
        }

        bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        new ConnectTask().execute();
    }

    private void printImage() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || bluetoothDevice == null || bluetoothSocket == null || !bluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {
            showToast("Please connect to a Bluetooth printer first");
            return;
        }

        // Load the image from a drawable resource
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bottomlogo);

        // Create an instance of PrintTask and pass the Bitmap
        new PrintTask(bitmap).execute();
    }

    private void showToast(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }

    private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permissions are not granted, request them
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BT_UUID);
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("Failed to connect to the printer");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class PrintTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private Bitmap imageToPrint;

        public PrintTask(Bitmap imageToPrint) {
            this.imageToPrint = imageToPrint;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    // Convert the bitmap to a monochrome image
                    byte[] imageData = convertBitmapToMonochrome(imageToPrint);

                    // Write the image data to the output stream
                    outputStream.write(imageData);
                    outputStream.flush();
                } else {
                    showToast("Bluetooth output stream is null");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast("Failed to print image");
            }
            return null;
        }

        private byte[] convertBitmapToMonochrome(Bitmap bitmap) {
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Calculate the number of bytes needed to store the monochrome image data
            int dataSize = (width + 7) / 8 * height;
            byte[] imageData = new byte[dataSize];

            int k = 0; // Index for imageData array

            // Iterate over each pixel in the bitmap
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    // Get the pixel color
                    int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                    // Calculate the grayscale intensity (average of RGB components)
                    int intensity = (Color.red(color) + Color.green(color) + Color.blue(color)) / 3;

                    // Set the corresponding bit in imageData based on intensity
                    if (intensity < 128) {
                        // Set bit to 1 for dark pixel
                        imageData[k / 8] |= (1 << (7 - (k % 8)));
                    }

                    // Move to the next bit in imageData
                    k++;
                }
            }

            return imageData;
        }


    }

    // Handle permission request result
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permissions granted, re-attempt to connect to the printer
                connectToBluetoothPrinter("YOUR_PRINTER_ADDRESS");
            } else {
                // Permissions denied, inform the user or handle the situation accordingly
                showToast("Bluetooth permissions are required to connect to the printer");
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}

i want to print image using thermal.This text in getting in print
